# cron service not running in ubuntu docker

Tags: cron, docker

I built a docker container with ubuntu 14.04 docker image. 
But I found cron job didn't run at all.

1. `apt-get install cron`

   Alreay installed
2. `service cron start` or `/etc/init.d/cron start` or `start cron`

   `pgrep cron` show nothing

What should I do?

Comment: It's a docker image. I wouldn't expect any init system to be running in it (to handle services). What do you need it for?

Comment: @muru  I use the docker container as a virtual machine(Isolated Environment). I want to be as usual as using ubuntu. Because docker is much faster than vmware, vagrant or something else.

Comment: if you intend to use it as a full fledged Ubuntu instance, then you might be better of using something like VirtualBox. Or maybe LXC or systemd-nspawn, if you want lightweight containers. This is not really the intended use case for Docker..